# Mark existing rows as duplicates when selecting with left join in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` to merge a table and view and the right table has duplicate items(usernames). I want to keep them but add another column to mark them as `isDuplicate='TRUE'`.

I wanted to use `CASE WHEN EXISTS` but can't get it to work correctly, it produces wrong results:

```
SELECT vc.id AS [id]
,vc.server AS [server]
,vc.username AS [vc_username]
,s.username AS [s_username]
,s.name AS [name]
,s.email AS [email]
,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT s.username WHERE vc.username = s.username)
       THEN 'TRUE'
       ELSE 'FALSE'
          END AS [isDuplicate]
FROM v_view vc
       LEFT JOIN s_table s ON vc.username = s.username
```

Ideally I would like to not mark the first occurence of a row as duplicate. E.g. first time username appears it is not marked as duplicate, second time it is a duplicate. If not possible then just mark all rows that don't have unique usernames as `isDuplicate='TRUE'`.

Example data:

View:

```
id   server   username
1    server1  user1
2    server2  user2
3    server3  user3
```

Table:

```
username    name     email
user1       Bob      bob@example.com
user1       BobAdmin bobadm@example.com
user2       John     john@example.com
user3       Daniel   daniel@example.com
user4       Adam     adam@example.com
```

Expected result:

```
id  server    vc_username  s_username   name      email                isDuplicate
1   server1   user1        user1        Bob       bob@example.com      FALSE
1   server1   user1        user1        BobAdmin  bobadm@example.com   TRUE
2   server2   user2        user2        John      john@example.com     FALSE
3   server3   user3        user3        Daniel    daniel@example.com   FALSE
```

Alternative option if first is not possible:

```
id  server    vc_username  s_username   name      email                isDuplicate
1   server1   user1        user1        Bob       bob@example.com      TRUE
1   server1   user1        user1        BobAdmin  bobadm@example.com   TRUE
2   server2   user2        user2        John      john@example.com     FALSE
3   server3   user3        user3        Daniel    daniel@example.com   FALSE
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for that, I just added sample data and the expected results, thanks!

Comment: Try again - this time include your IsDuplicate column in your expected outputs. And since you left join, provide an example of that as well.

Comment: @SMor thanks for pointing that out! Fixed.

Comment: Aside: How do you expect a `case` expression that returns `'TRUE'` or `'FALSE'` to result in `'yes'` or `'no'` in your expected result? Did someone skip their coffee or tea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()` or `count(*)`.  To tag all duplicate user names:

```
SELECT . . .,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY username) > 1
             THEN 'TRUE'
             ELSE 'FALSE'
       END) AS [isDuplicate]
FROM v_view vc LEFT JOIN
     s_table s
     ON vc.username = s.username;
```

You would use `row_number() . . . = 1` if you wanted to identify as duplicates all but one of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need EXISTS clause again. You can go for either CASE logic or IIF logic.

```sql
SELECT vc.id AS [id]
,vc.server AS [server]
,vc.username AS [vc_username]
,s.username AS [s_username]
,s.name AS [name]
,s.email AS [email]
,IIF(s.username IS NOT NULL,'TRUE','FALSE') AS IsDuplicate
FROM v_view vc
       LEFT JOIN s_table s ON vc.username = s.username

Or

SELECT vc.id AS [id]
,vc.server AS [server]
,vc.username AS [vc_username]
,s.username AS [s_username]
,s.name AS [name]
,s.email AS [email]
,CASE WHEN s.username IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS IsDuplicate
FROM v_view vc
       LEFT JOIN s_table s ON vc.username = s.username
```